# defgroup longer than a line + different caracters doxygen VHDL

Tags: vhdl, doxygen

I am trying to document a code using doxygen. The version I am running is 1.6.1.
I have documented a VHDL file, and when defining a new group I get a different encoding. I have set the encoding as ISO-8859-1 (I have tried others encodings as well, same result. I am Spanish).
Only in this file I get the accents wrong as follow:
**Contador CÃ­clico** 
The result should be: Contador Cíclico. (Accents work fine in the rest of files)

In addition, when I try to name a new group with more characters than a line I cannot see the second line. I have tried <>, (), and {} but neither of those work:

```
--! @defgroup Registro_doble_puerto_16_bits_lim Registro doble puerto de
--! 16 bits límite
```

I have looked for both of those issues but I did not find an answer.

Thank you very much,
Antonio

Comment: Version 1.6.1. is a bit old, what are the results with the current 1.8.11 version?

Comment: I am using centos 6.7 and as far as I know I cannot update the doxygen version.
Do you think this has something to do with the version? If so I would consider updating the OS.

Thanks!!

Comment: VHDL files are restricted to the ASCII encoding. Please check if (all) your tools support ANSI, ISO-8859-x or multi-byte encodings like UTF-8. Some tools have command line arguments to explicitly allow this.

Comment: VHDL -1993 required all characters belong to the ISO 8859-1 8 bit set. -2002 relaxed that for comments although a VHDL tool isn't required to display them correctly, the presence or absence of comments has no effect on the meaning of a design description. Ã is an 8859-1 graphic character position value x"C3" also used as the first byte in a multi-byte sequence in some character sets. Graphic characters uses in extended identifiers  and bit string literals may be rendered incorrectly when not using 8859-1 in doxygen suggesting non 8859-1 comments should be handled separately.

Comment: I cannot tell for sure but the chance that this has to do with the old version is quite high. You don't have to update the OS but you can download the doxygen source and compile it. Maybe there also newer installation packages for doxygen with centos.

Comment: I have updated the version to the 1.8.12 and the same behaviour. In fact, for some reason doxygen does not detect all the files that was detecting before with the 1.6.1 version. Is not detecting the graphs like FSM either.
Thanks!!